# Running an NPM script with command expansion parses result before returning it - unlike bash

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, npm

If I run `echo "$(echo 'A\nB')"` in my shell, I get an output of:

```
A\nB
```

If however I place the same code in an NPM script:

```
"scripts": {
  "example": "echo \"$(echo 'A\nB')\""
}
```

Then run that script: `npm run -s example`.

I get an output with the `\n` replaced with an actual new line:

```
A
B
```

How can I disable this interpreting of the string? Why does NPM treat command expansion differently than the shell?

This only happens with command expansion: `$(some command here)`

Comment: It appears that it does treat command expansion differently than shell. Because switches supported for `echo` in shell get printed when using the above.

Answer (score 1):

Part of this is `npm`'s behavior, and part of it is because you're writing the script in a JSON file.

`\n` is a JSON escape sequence for a newline.

`"echo \"$(echo 'A\nB')\""` will be passed to `npm` as:

```
echo "$(echo 'A
B')"
```

However, there is definitely some problems with `npm`'s handling of newlines (possibly related to the fact that `\n` is also a JS escape sequence).

By trial & error, I figured out that this works:

```
"scripts": {
  "example": "echo \"$(echo 'A\\\\\\\\nB')\""
}
```

Without JSON escaping, that would be `echo "$(echo 'A\\\\nB')"`.

That's just weird. Perhaps you should file an issue with `npm`.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

---

#### Update

npm@6.14.5 works with less slashes...? leaving old answer for posterity, and I didn't check if it's changed on all versions.

```
"scripts": {
  "example": "echo \"$(echo 'A\\\\\\nB')\""
}
```

Without JSON escaping, that would be `echo "$(echo 'A\\\nB')"`.

Comment: Interesting about the fact that because its json, thanks for the explanation